# Handling Null Reference in DatePicker

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I am having the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My coding is:

```vb
If (DirectCast(drv.Cells(4).FindControl("rdp_clsDate"), RadDatePicker).DbSelectedDate).ToString <> "" Then
    Dim ClsDate As Date = DirectCast(drv.Cells(4).FindControl("rdp_clsDate"), RadDatePicker).DbSelectedDate
    aa_ml.closeDate = ClsDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
Else
    aa_ml.closeDate = ""
End If
```

Here `CloseDate` is not mandatory. So I may give or I may not give. When I give the close date the codes are working properly and the records are stored in the table. But when I did not give the close date I can't run the procedure. When debugging, the execution stops at this line

```vb
If (DirectCast(drv.Cells(4).FindControl("rdp_clsDate"), RadDatePicker).DbSelectedDate).ToString <> "" Then
```

and I get the above error.

How can I change the code to handle the situation when I am not giving the `closedate`?

I am using oracle as backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `ToString()` on `DbSelectedDate` which is a null field if no date is selected in your date picker.

Split it into two lines and add a check for null before running `ToString()`

Comment: hi, now i cant ask question . what should i do.. Anyone please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if [RadDatePicker.DbSelectedDate Property](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/p_telerik_web_ui_raddatepicker_dbselecteddate.html) is `Nothing` or not first before converting it to a string. Try this code

```vb
Dim rdp_clsDate As RadDatePicker = DirectCast(drv.Cells(4).FindControl("rdp_clsDate"), RadDatePicker)
If rdp_clsDate.DbSelectedDate IsNot Nothing AndAlso rdp_clsDate.DbSelectedDate.ToString() <> "" Then
    Dim ClsDate As Date = rdp_clsDate.DbSelectedDate
    aa_ml.closeDate = ClsDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
Else
    aa_ml.closeDate = ""
End If
```